# Viewing sqlite3_stmt* in command window

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have inherited a SQLite database that is poorly commented and I need to understand what it is querying and receiving. Is there a way to see the value a `sqlite3_stmt` pointer is pointing to? Is it something that can be printed to the console in a `printf()` or `NSLog()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to trace the compiled statement. I've found a solution with the help of this question:

The sqlite3_trace command triggers a callback, which you need to code yourself. Once the trace is turned on it will execute for the rest of the program.

I've got all my database access routines in a single class, and I've used this as the callback function (it's a C function, not a method).

```
void traceCallback( void* udp, const char* sql ) 
{ 
    printf("{SQL} [%s]\n", sql); 
}
```

I turned the trace on in an init database method: it's turned on once the database is opened.

```
-(void)initializeDatabase 
{
    NSString *path = [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    // open the db
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        sqlite3_trace(db, traceCallback, NULL);
    else {
        // error - cleanup
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Error opening db");
        NSLog(@"Path: %@",path);
    }
}
```

This will turn a SQL statement with bound variables into a string.
From this:

```
const char *sql2 = "select a.key, b.key from words a left outer join known_words b on a.key = b.word_id where a.word_foreign = :word_foreign";
```

To this:

```
{SQL} [select a.key, b.key from words a left outer join known_words b on a.key = b.word_id    where a.word_foreign = 'bak.']
```